# Module error "_jpype.so invalid ELF header" on Amazon Lambda

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, jpype, amazon-athena

I am trying to upload python code and modules in Amazon Lambda, my python code accesses Amazon Athena, runs there a query and inserts results in S3. When I save and run my package in Lambda I am getting this error:

> "errorType": "ImportError",  "errorMessage":
>   "/var/task/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_jpype.so: invalid ELF header"

I am using JPype1==0.6.2,Mac OS.
Any suggestions as to why this is happening or how to resolve it would be very appreciated.